# How to remove the ticks at the beginning and ending of the slider and how to add thickness for ticks?

Tags: wpf, xaml

In the below attached image, I didn't add the ticks at the beginning and ending of the Slider. By default it is adding.How to remove the ticks at the beginning and ending of the Slider. And also How to add the thickness  of ticks?

Below is the image which I designed.

[Designed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EOEd.png)

Below is the expected Image.

[Expected Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6601U.png)

Below is my style for Slider

```
 <Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButton" TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                <Border  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#c3c3c3" Background="#c3c3c3" Height="3"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButton1" TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="#e94480"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#e94480" Height="3"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Ellipse Height="13" Width="13" Fill="#e94480"></Ellipse>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="Slider"  TargetType="Slider">
    <Grid >
        <TickBar Visibility="Visible"  Fill="#e94480"  Placement="Top" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="16"  Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
        <Track  x:Name="PART_Track">
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton1}"  Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumb}"  />
            </Track.Thumb>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" />
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        </Track>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="Horizontal_Slider" TargetType="Slider">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="21" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="104" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Slider}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And  I have added the Ticks in code

```
            double totoalDuration = 0;
            SliderProgress.Ticks.Clear();
        foreach (var item in _multiVideosPropertiesList)
        {
            totoalDuration += item.Play_duration;
            SliderProgress.Ticks.Add(totoalDuration);
        }
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please show what you've tried, with a [mcve], explain exactly what went wrong and what _specifically_ you need help with. Note that in WPF, often you can modify the visual presentation of a control by replacing its template. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27287315) to a related question for some information on how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide ticks at Min and Max in WPF Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432798/hide-ticks-at-min-and-max-in-wpf-slider)